What type of glue or adhesive to use from polyethylene to fiber reinforced nylon (anka couplings)?
I am using the local Water District recommended pipes for the water supply line. It is 200psi polyethylene:

Finding couplers for this stuff is very difficult. I can not use the barbs or hose bibs because the pipe is in a 40 inch deep trench (can't bang it in to fit over the male barb)  and the new pipe retains its strong bend (so can't attach a screw-in fitting to use hose bib/threaded connetions).
The only thing I could come up with is using a non-traditional push on fitting. This advertises as "Fiberglass Reinforced Nylon".  I do have a Tee-fitting and it seems quite strong.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-ANKA-1-in-x-1-in-Fiberglass-Reinforced-Nylon-Straight-Coupling-ASC1/305018968

The Polyethylene pipe does fit inside the threaded clamp. So far so good. But I don't want to trust just that clamping action: let's get some glue or strong adhesive on it.
But what type of glue/adhesive to use?

maybe you should first be asking if glue is required

So where does the local water district get the couplings they use? they obviously do - they won't be using cowboy methods...

Is it that they're plastic that's giving your pause? https://www.aymcdonald.com/en/product/water-works-service-fittings-couplings-same-end-connection/74758-22-1-coupling-cts-x-cts-nl--5141-134

@SolarMike. The water district only uses metal piping.  That's impossibly expensive.

@jsotola Apparently yes that should be asked. I had not used any other materials for which adhesives are not prescribed - but ran into verbage last night that that is the case for PE . I am not completely satisfied with the weaker connection provided by this product (vs barbed fittings / 2 clamps) so had/have been hoping to supplement with a glue/adhesive.  I just can't win here it seems.

While it was never in my top ten fun things to do, I have always used the barb fittings to connect those pipes.  I found some lubrication and warm heat helps without needing to spend a few years at a gym.  Taking them apart is much different and knives were usually used.

@crip659.  The barbs provide strong confident connections. Unfortunately there is a 13 feet length going around a slight bend (and the pipe itself remembers its coiled past with a vengeance) so  there is zero possibility of inserting the pipe over the barb by force.  Some kind of hose bib will be needed on both ends to allow independent insertions on both sides. Putting this all together is a parts nightmare and I'm in double digit hours trying but still plugging away.

From the Anka instruction PDF here is a cross section of the sealing system:

This setup looks in function rather like the typical hose barb with a metal band clamp commonly used for garden hoses.
It does not look like glue would be needed, just like the garden hose barbs don't need glue.

Yes these are supposed to work as is (with pipe thread/dope as added protection). I am however not completely convinced.  The connection is not as strong as what a husky barbed connection with two clamps provides.  I'm burying this down forty inches and any issues will result in huge water losses.  Any adhesives that might be added to improve the seal/connection would  be welcome

FWIW I don't necessarily trust the plastic nut to stay in one piece under tension for a long time. If I ever used these I'd try to add a larger hose clamp over the nut to add extra squeeze surrounding the nut to help it stay together. FWIW2 if the nut were cut off (oscillating saw?) the area over the barb would be available for some pretty decent single or double hose clamps.

This is a partial and under-construction answer representing my ongoing discoveries.  There is verbage that adhesives / glue are not recommended/prescribed for polyethylene (PE).  This does not represent a happy result since reinforcement to the anka fittings would be sought.
Apparently there are products that work with PE but they are not in the common domain. One of the companies Permabond I found in fact does not sell directly to consumers.  I am attempting to contact them anyways to obtain more information including recommendations on products available to homeowners and/or other approaches to PE fittings.
